# Adding second and third authors on new line

Tags: titles, author, affiliation

I am trying to get the first author's name and their affiliation in the middle of the first line and then the second and third author's name on the second line but I keep getting two on the first one and a the last author on the second line (I want a triangle but keep getting an upside-down triangle).

I have tried the following method and a couple of variations but none of them seem to work.

```
\author{ 
Name1 Surname1\\
 \texttt{$mail1@uni.edu$} 
 \newline \and
Name2 Surname2\\ 
 \texttt{$mail2@uni.edu$} 
  \and 
Name3 Surmame3\\ 
 \texttt{$mail3@uni.edu$} 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico It's an article. \documentclass[14pt]{article}

Comment: An email address is not a mathematical formula. Why do you put it between $ signs?

Comment: @hair-splitter No reason. I saw that template some time ago and kept using it, tbh. I've tried changing it but I think it looks better this way

Comment: `\texttt{$mail2@uni.edu$}` is a bad method. For example, use `\textit{mail2@uni.edu}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the minipage ambient:

```
\author{ 
\begin{minipage}[t,l]{.45\textwidth}
    Name1 Surname1\\
    \texttt{$mail1@uni.edu$}  \\
\end{minipage}
\noindent\\
\begin{minipage}[t,r]{.6\textwidth}
        Name2 Surname2\\
    \texttt{$mail2@uni.edu$} \\
\end{minipage}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t,l]{.6\textwidth}
Name3 Surmame3\\ 
\texttt{$mail3@uni.edu$}
\end{minipage}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added a few \ centering to get it to center correctly but it worked perfectly